# Does the Application name in Package Name has to be unique for google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Does the app name in the package name make a difference? does it have to be unique? or would the app be rejected while publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can release an app named the exact same title string as another app, the package name (in reverse web URL format) is what keeps it unique, for example com.mywebsite.myappname or com.mywebsite.mysuitename.myappname, but I would suggest a creative name for something going on the market!

The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.

Problem: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

Comment: So basically if package name is com.blah.test it won't clash with for instance  com.doubleblah.test?

Comment: Thanks, cause weirdly my apk keeps getting rejected so I thought it might be the problem, I already changed the image, title, screenshots and had nothing else left to change so I thought this might be the problem

Comment: my pleasure @busted13